# 3x3 noughts and crosses and determining if there is a winner

Tags: python

This is for an assignment at my uni and the question is:

Winner!

Using the function line_winner(line), now we can implement the winner function! The function winner(board), will inspect every row, column and diagonals to check whether any player has won the game. If there is a winner (i.e. the function line_winner(line) returned something other than None) then function winner(board) also returns the winner. If no winner is yet to be found, it returns None.

Complete function winner(board).

For example:

```
Test    Result
board = [['X', ' ', 'O'], [' ', 'O', ' '], ['X', ' ', ' ']]
print(winner(board))
None
board = [['X', ' ', 'O'], ['X', 'O', ' '], ['X', ' ', ' ']]
print(winner(board))
X
```

This is the code I've come up with:

```
def winner(board):
    """noughts and crosses game and checks if a row or column or diagonal is a winner"""
    row_ = []
    for row_number in range(3):
        row_.append(board[row_number])
    column_ = []
    for col_number in range(3):
        column_.append(list(board[0][col_number] + board[1][col_number] + board[2][col_number]))
    diagonal_0 = []
    diagonal_1 = []
    for selected_diagonal in range(2):
        if selected_diagonal == 0:
            diagonal_0.append(list(board[0][0] + board[1][1] + board[2][2]))
        else:
            diagonal_1.append(list(board[0][2] + board[1][1] + board[2][0]))
    total = row_ + column_ + diagonal_0 + diagonal_1
    res = None
    for line in total:
        if line[0] == line[1] == line[2]:
            if line[0] == 'X':
                res = 'X'
            elif line[0] == 'O':
                res = 'O'
            elif line[0] == ' ':
                res = None
    return res
```

However its 23 statements long and the question only allows for 20. is there anyway i can shorten it??
also it has to pass these checks:

```
board = [['X', ' ', 'O'], [' ', 'O', ' '], ['X', ' ', ' ']]
print(winner(board))
None

board = [['X', ' ', 'O'], [' ', 'O', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ']]
print(winner(board))
None

board = [['X', ' ', 'O'], ['X', 'X', ' '], ['X', ' ', 'X']]
print(winner(board))
X

board = [['O', ' ', 'O'], ['O', 'X', ' '], ['O', ' ', 'X']]
print(winner(board))
O
```

Comment: You are actually asking for the solution, which is really your job. What gain is there if you ask someone else for the solution?

Answer (score 0):

First, the algorithm is not correct. As soon as you have determined that `res` is "X" or "O", you should exit the loop and return that result, otherwise you risk that in a next iteration of that loop this result is lost again.

To shorten the code, here are some ideas:

- The variable `row_` gets a copy of `board`. This is not really useful. You can just use `board` where you use `row_` and omit the latter.
- The loop to populate the diagonal lists is a bit of an over kill. Just assign the two diagonal lists to the respective variables. The loop can then be deleted.
- Beside the error you need to fix in the final loop, you can also omit the test on " ". Just do nothing when in that case, and continue the loop.

Please do these changes yourself. If you really cannot make it work, then use the spoiler below, ... but you really should not need to.

> ```
>  def winner(board):
>      column_ = []
>      for col_number in range(3):
>          column_.append([board[0][col_number], board[1][col_number], board[2][col_number]])
>      diagonal_0 = [[board[0][0], board[1][1], board[2][2]]]
>      diagonal_1 = [[board[0][2], board[1][1], board[2][0]]]
>      for line in board + column_ + diagonal_0 + diagonal_1:
>          if line[0] == line[1] == line[2] and line[0] != " ":
>              return line[0]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The quick and easy way is that if you know the games of naughts and crosses will be played only in a 3x3 square and you'll never need to generalise for larger squares then there are only 8 possible winning rows. That is 3 horizontal, 3 vertical and 2 diagonals. The board gives three horizontal rows (I assumed the board describes three rows though it does not matter), so what we can do is add the additional columns and diagonals then iterate over them and check if any one of them is a winning row. You could generalise this approach very easily but I'll leave that up to you if you need it

```
def winner(board):
    board.append([board[0][0], board[1][0], board[2][0]])  # vertical left
    board.append([board[0][1], board[1][1], board[2][1]])  # vertical center
    board.append([board[0][2], board[1][2], board[2][2]])  # vertical right
    board.append([board[0][0], board[1][1], board[2][2]])  # diag bl to tr
    board.append([board[0][2], board[1][1], board[2][0]])  # diag tl to be

    for row in board:
        if row[0] == row[1] == row[2] and row[0] != " ":
            return row[0]
```